# Micronaut, OpenAPI (Swagger), Lombok and fluent API

Tags: swagger, lombok, openapi, micronaut

the last two days I had the opportunity to play around with Micronaut.

It looks nice and I like the built in support for OpenAPI (Swagger). I managed to have the OpenAPI documentation in a local Swagger-UI and I was able to create some documentation which is shown in Swagger-UI as expected.

Then I moved to a little real world project which uses Lombok with fluent API which is configured in lombok.config

```
lombok.accessors.fluent=true
```

This setting causes Lombok not to create getter/setters, but something like

```
private String name;
public String name()...
public void name(String name)...
```

Unfortunately the OpenAPI documentation generation does not work properly in this setup - it is skipped. It seems the getter convention is required.

Is there any Micronaut-Swagger-Extension available which support the lombok fluent accessors?
If there is none, can you please give me any hint which piece of code scans the methods for annotations so I can extend it?

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE 1:
For better problem reproduction I enhanced the Micronaut Java Example: https://github.com/flexguse/micronaut-examples/tree/master/hello-world-java

The README.md contains detailed information, how to configure lombok to get the missing OpenAPI documentation.

Answer (score 2):

No, Afaik there is no Micronaut Swagger extension for Lombok at the moment.

The [OpenApiApplicationVisitor.java](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-openapi/blob/master/openapi/src/main/java/io/micronaut/openapi/visitor/OpenApiApplicationVisitor.java#L70) is responsible for generating OpenAPI documentation. And, if you are planning to work on micronaut-openapi for supporting the Lombok fluent accessors I would be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint, I'll have a look at OpenApiApplicationVisitor as soon I have some time left.